# pass a javascript value to a linkbutton's CommandArgument

Tags: javascript, asp.net, commandargument

i need to pass a javascript value named $.galleria.current to a linkbutton's CommandArgument declared so :

> < asp:linkbutton id="prevBut" runat="server" OnCommand="load_com"  CommandArgument=place_javascript_value Text="previous" />

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you set a linkbutton with a command argument and then examine the HTML... there's nothing there to carry the "command argument". So it's not in the page. Well I suppose it may be in the encrypted ViewState, but that's no use, so you can't get to it I think.